# How to get Location (Country) for Office 365 account in PowerApp?

Tags: office365, powerapps

Is it possible to get this Office 365 or Microsoft 365 Location (Country) property for current user in PowerApp:

[Location (Country) property in the user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pqgM.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this in PowerApps.

**The easiest way is:**

1. Add the `Office 365 Users` Connector to your PowerApp

- `View` / `Data Sources` / `Connectors` / `Office 365 Users`

2. Insert a Label and set its Text Property to...

- `First(Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:User().Email}).Country).Country`

[image]

3. Better yet, to get ALL the O365 User Properties, add the following to the OnStart Property of your app...

- `ClearCollect(colUserData, Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:User().Email}))`
- You'll now have a table of all the logged in users O365 Attributes

**EDIT 10/24/2020:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for response @SeaDude - however, I tried this approach already and that property (Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:User().Email}).Country) is empty  though the Location is set to Australia in Office 365 as per screenshot.

Comment: PowerApps Label Controls require a FIELD. The code you show above is a RECORD. You need to wrap your code above in `First(...).Country` as I lined out in the answer.

Comment: Yes, have tried this also First(Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:User().Email})).Country - it's still empty. I suppose the Microsoft 365 Location property that's is displayed on the licence tab is something else.

Comment: You still have the syntax incorrect. Please check my answer above. `First(Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:User().Email}).Country).Country`. The Text `.Country` appears TWICE in the statement.

Comment: Hm. I'm interested to see how you come out. I added a GIF of the process. Works in my tenant.

Comment: Thanks for posting the GIF with the process! I'm wondering what property value it displays in the end in your case? The one I'm trying to get is Office.com->Admin->Users->select user->see the Location. It's on the screenshot I attached to the original question.
I presume what you are displaying is stored in some other profile location (e.g. Country you edit in SharePoint/Delve profile.
The one I'm trying to get is different.

Comment: The above solution given in the answer, perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This function is no longer supported in powerapps directly from
Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:User().Email}).Country).Country)

Comment: I disagree (see EDIT Oct. 24th 2020 in my answer). I just ran the same code (`First(Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:User().Email}).Country).Country` and my Country is displayed without issue.